# BigInteger.isProbablePrime seems much more certain than it says it is

Tags: java, primes, biginteger

I understand the [certainty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)) argument to mean:

> certainty - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate: if the call returns true the probability that this BigInteger is prime exceeds (1 - 1/2<sup>certainty</sup>)

From my experiments, it seems to exceed it by quite a lot! The code below finds "probable primes" between 2 and 1 million and checks against a set of definite primes to see if it was a false positive.

I'm using a certainty argument of 2. I therefore expect that only 75% of "probable primes" will be actual primes. (1 - 1/2<sup>2</sup> = 0.75 = 75%.)

Actually, it gets it right 99.9% of the time.

Is my understanding of the meaning of "certainty" correct? I suspect it might not be if the certainty I've seen experimentally exceeds my expectation by so much.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.BitSet;

import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class PrimesCalculator {
    public final int max;
    private final BitSet sieve;  // Set of all non-primes from 2 to max.

    public PrimesCalculator(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        sieve = new BitSet(max+1);
        for (int n = 2, sqrtMax = (int) sqrt(max); n < sqrtMax; n++)
            for (int i = n * 2; i < max; i += n)
                sieve.set(i);
    }

    public boolean isPrime(int n) {
        return !sieve.get(n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimesCalculator calc = new PrimesCalculator(1_000_000);
        int numPrimes = 0;
        int numProbablePrimes = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < calc.max; i++)
            if (BigInteger.valueOf(i).isProbablePrime(2)) {
                numProbablePrimes++;
                if (calc.isPrime(i))
                    numPrimes++;
            }
        System.out.printf("%s/%s (%s%%)%n", numPrimes, numProbablePrimes, numPrimes / (numProbablePrimes / 100.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that there are other ranges of primes for which you get considerably poorer results. It might be that many of the first 1M integers are the "easy ones" to check.

Comment: The implementation references ANSI X9.80 for the logic.

Comment: Even at a certainty of `2`,  `BigInteger b = (BigInteger.TWO.pow(82589933)).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);` which is the largest known prime takes a long time (at least 10 minutes on my PC) to return.  And that is small since the largest BigInteger permitted takes `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as  an argument to the `pow` method.

Comment: The probability is related solely to one of the internal underlying tests called the miller-rabin primality test. *Most* composites will be detected rather easily, but a few stubborn ones are harder to reveal. That probability is a worst case probability in case the composite you are testing just happens to be one of the stubborn ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These statements frequently cause confusion. I will attempt to explain it a little better here.

Java's `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()` contains no optimizations for small integers at all, except 0, 1, and 2 are treated as special cases and all even integers except 2 are immediately declared composite. This will be true as of the time this was written.

All other odd integers are checked for primality using the Miller-Rabin (MR) primality test. In addition, if the integer is 100 bits or larger it is also checked with something called the Lucas-Lehmer test.

MR is a complicated primality test whose explanation and analysis are beyond the scope of an SO answer. The key point is that, as far as MR is concerned, not all composites are created equal. A very, very tiny fraction are *stubborn*, which means it's much, much harder to discover their compositeness. A few examples: amongst the small odd composites, 91, 703, and 1891 are stubborn. MR overcomes this by trying multiple randomized attempts to discover the compositeness of an integer. Rabin's analysis shows that, for the most stubborn composites, a single randomized attempt still has at least a 75% (3/4) probability of revealing its compositeness.

The algorithm has no way to know which composites are stubborn. And for cryptography, getting a number you're told is prime but is actually composite can be potentially disastrous. So, for safety, the formula for `certainty` assumes that *all* the numbers it tests for primality are are stubborn composites or real primes. The `certainty` argument is almost equivalent to specifying the number of randomized attempts that the MR algorithm needs to perform. In reality, the relationship between the `certainty` argument and the number of randomized attempts in the Java implementation seems more complicated and I don't completely understand it myself just from reading the source code.

But remember I said that the fraction of composites that are stubborn is very, very small. Almost every composite you test is not stubborn, and will fail MR after only a single randomized attempt as primes get larger. That's why your success rate appears to be 99.9%.

As an experiment to see how different composites perform, change your program to instead just repeatedly try confirming the compositeness of, say, 1891. You will see something closer to only 75% success.

A list of relatively small MR-stubborn composites is [here](https://oeis.org/A090659).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you've cited is correct.

> certainty - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate: if the call returns true the probability that this BigInteger is prime exceeds (1 - 1/2<sup>certainty</sup>)

99.9% indeed exceeds 1 - 1/(2<sup>2</sup>) = 3/4, so there's nothing wrong with what you've shown us.

The implementation makes no guarantees that that's *exactly* the probability, it just provides an implementation whose error is *definitely bounded* by that certainty.

Most quality primality testers will have lots of optimizations for small primes, or rather, numbers whose divisors are small composite numbers.  These likely kick in before the random aspects of the algorithm, resulting in higher-than-usual accuracy for small primes.

Comment: Seems a bit vague

Comment: @MorganS42: Why?  "99.9% >= 0.75" is exactly the answer you get by reading the documentation carefully.

Comment: That's true and I do think it answers the question, I had not noticed that detail in the documentation. Nonetheless 99.9% is significantly higher than 75%, why so? I know you said that it's because only small numbers were being tested, but when is it no longer considered small? A million? A billion? etc. The BigInteger class defines the SMALL_PRIME_THRESHOLD at 95; I am aware that there would be optimisations for small primes larger then this. Even still I would expect a true certainty of 90%, 95% even 99%, but 99.9% is on a whole other level. After reading your answer I am still left puzzled.

Comment: `1-1/2^certainty` is the ***lower bound***.  There's nothing in the definition saying the actual value must be close to the lower bound, only that it will be greater than the lower bound, i.e. some (any) value between `1-1/2^certainty` and `1`.  `0.999` is definitely within that range.

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily about primes smaller than 95, but composite numbers with factors <= 95.  A huge fraction of all numbers -- and you are _testing_ all numbers -- have factors <= 95.  Most primes used for crypto -- a relevant application of BigInteger -- are on the order of 10^77 at least.

Comment: *Most quality primality testers will have lots of optimizations for small primes...* Java's has no such optimizations.